# Adding a custom reference point on scatter plot

Tags: powerbi, scatter-plot

I am working on a scatter chart to display Speed (X-axis) vs Consumption (Y-axis) of different vehicle designs. The goal of the report is to examine that for the same design, is the particular vehicle more or less efficient than that of others in the market.

I would like to know if it is possible for the user to input the specifications for the particular vehicle's X-axis and Y-axis within the report itself so that the user can compare it visually.

As seen in the image below, say the user has input the specifications for the specific vehicle when it is laden (in red) and when it is ballast (in green).

[image: intended outcome for scatter chart]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few options:

1. When in Direct Query or Mixed Mode:

   - [Embed PowerApps in your report](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/visuals/power-bi-visualization-powerapp) to capture data and write it to your data store and then refresh the visual.
   - Build a companion App (in the tech of your choice) to update the DB with your parameters.
2. When in Import Mode: Use [what if parameters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/transform-model/desktop-what-if) to provide the input.

[image]

Comment: I have created new what-if parameter inputs, however, is it possible for me to overlay them on the existing scatter chart? I understand that for the scatter chart, they can only accept 1 variable for X and Y axis respectively. Have not got to trying PowerApps as I am still experimenting with it.

Comment: Nice - glad you found a solution! Please accept my response as an answer.